# Error in running server via node and express

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon

i am still new in backend but i am facing an error since yesterday whenever i try to run my server. BELOW IS MY CODE AND ERROR

```
 const express = require("express");
const app = express();

PORT = 8443;

app.listen("PORT", () => {
    console.log("Server up and running")
});
```

AND HERE IS MY ERROR

```
    events.js:288
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EACCES: permission denied PORT
←[90m    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1292:21)←[39m
←[90m    at listenInCluster (net.js:1357:12)←[39m
←[90m    at Server.listen (net.js:1456:5)←[39m
    at Function.listen (C:\Users\AbTorres9\Desktop\YelpCamp\node_modules\←[4mexpress←[24m\lib\application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\AbTorres9\Desktop\YelpCamp\app.js:6:5)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)←[39m
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
←[90m    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1336:8)←[39m
←[90m    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'EACCES'←[39m,
  errno: ←[32m'EACCES'←[39m,
  syscall: ←[32m'listen'←[39m,
  address: ←[32m'PORT'←[39m,
  port: ←[33m-1←[39m
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Are you running it locally on remotely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a view normal JavaScript things. Like defining `port`. And the `.listen` function takes in the port variable rather than a string saying `"PORT"`
See working example:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 8443;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}!`));
```

Comment: i know you are suggesting a way of writing this but still its not working for me.

Comment: Are you getting the same error using my code example? Because it works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PORT = 8443;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
     console.log("Server up and running")
});
```

you had some errors first of all you did not initialized the PORT and second you passed PORT as string in app.listen()

Comment: i got it thanks, how can i make such a small and stupid mistake. God bless me!

Comment: glad to help. please upvote the ans if it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

@Abhishek, I think on which port are you using that is block by your environment kindly allow it on the firewall or just disable the firewall and access again it works for you!!

Comment: i turned off firewall still it is showing me the same error :( i guess i should restart my system after doing that

Answer (score 0):

You should use the **variable** and not the **string** in the `app.listen()` function. Try to use something like this:

```
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("Server up and running")
});
```

Comment: i got it thanks, how can i make such a small and stupid mistake. God bless me!

Comment: Its fine. I make always tiny mistakes resulting to bugs.